# Behavioursubject on subscribe emitting old and new value after unsubscribe

Tags: angular, reactjs

I am using Behaviour subject to get the version selected.

```
public messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(release);
currentMessage =this.messageSource.asObservable()
setCheckedVersion(chkVersion){
    console.log(chkVersion)
    this.messageSource.next(chkVersion)
}
```

In slider component I am setting the Version on click which is used to generate the chart.IN slider component

```
setCheckedVersion(chkVersion){
    this.messageSource.next(chkVersion)
}
```

In chart component i am subscribing to the changes

```
this.curMsg= this._sharedService.currentMessage.subscribe((chkVersion)=>
  {this.checked_versions=chkVersion})
```

Everything works fine but when i change the route and come back to chart component it is getting subscribe two times.For this i have unsubscribed this in OnDestroy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    gantt.clearAll()
    // this.curView.
    this.curMsg.unsubscribe()
}
```

But when i subscribing again it is getting two value one is the latest data and one more which was selected before routing.
How can i get only the latest data?

Comment: I am not sure of my answer and I cannot test it in this moment, but I think that you are looking using a  `Subject` instead of a `BehaviorSubject`. The difference is that, at subscription, the `BehaviourSubject` will provide its value while the `Subject` will wait for the next update to fire.

Comment: I am getting the data.But problem is it is emitting value for old and new also.How can i cancel and subscribe to latest value emitted.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a stackblitz. It doesn't have to use charts or anything. Just reproduce the problem with the subject.

Comment: give me some min

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue while using `Behavior Subject`. Switching to `Subject` resolved the issue.

`Behavior Subject`, in extreme basic terms, keeps previous data for reuse by all subscribers (which can be retrieved at any point without using observable code), and will return that old data indefinitely. You can also add more data to it, which I think is why you're seeing the effect that you are.

`Subject` returns and forgets, so switch to that and you should be golden.

Comment: generally i cant switch to subject because i need last status if it is not set.Problem here is after unsubscribe i am getting both old and new data.i am guessing if switchMap can help me